# Mocking a Laravel Command Dependency

Tags: php, laravel, command, phpunit, laravel-5.7

As the official Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#command-structure) says so I made the following command:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Model\Report;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Exception;

class ExportAnualReport extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = "Print Anual Report";

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = "report:anual";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle(Report $report): int
    {
        //@todo Implement Upload
        try {
            $reportData = $report->getAnualReport();
            $this->table($reportData['headers'], $reportData['data']);
            return 0;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->error($e->getMessage());
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But instead of the approach used in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56853267/4706711)  I already follow laravel's approach and recommendation and I utilize Dependency Injection in order to insert my model as a Service.

So I the meantime I thought it would be a good Idea to Unit test it:

```
namespace Tests\Command;

use App\Model\Report;
use Tests\TestCase;

class TripAdvisorUploadFeedCommandTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testFailAnualReport()
    {
        $this->artisan('report:anual')->assertExitCode(1);
    }

    public function testSucessAnualReport()
    {
        $this->artisan('report:anual')->assertExitCode(0);
    }
}
```

But In my case I already have inject the Eloquent Model `Report` into my command via the `handle` function, so I want to mock the `Report` object instance Instead of hitting the actual database.

For the record the `Report` Object is the following:

```
namespace App\Model

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

class Report extends Model
{
     /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'myapp_report_records';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'report_id';

    public function getAnualReport()
    {
        $now=Carbon::now();
        $oneYearBefore=new Carbon($now);
        $oneYearBefore->modify('-1 year');

        $results=$this->where('date','>',$oneYearBefore)->where('date','<',$now)->all();

        if(empty($results)){
            throw new ModelNotFoundException();
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```

So how I can mock the provided `Report` model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need to create a mock of your model report class then you need to bind it to the container. this way whenever you call the report model class in your command class you'll have a mocked model class with the specific response that you are expecting.

```
$this->app->instance(Report::class, \Mockery::mock(Report::class, function($mock){
            $mock->shouldReceive('getAnualReport')->andReturn(['headers'=>'any values', 'data'=>'any values']);
        }));
```

Comment: Also how I can tear down the mocked service?

Comment: You can have tearDown method in every test class in laravel, when you use that method and call the parent::tearDown(); it'll automatically clear all of the mocked objects. But i recall there are some issues with removing mock objects.You can also take a look at this link http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/phpunit_integration.html

Answer (score 1):

The official way is:

```php
$this->mock(Report::class, function($mock){
    $mock->shouldReceive(.....)
        ->withArgs([...])
        ->andReturn(....);
});
```

### Under the hood

Under the hood this method does the following:

```php
protected function mock($abstract, Closure $mock = null)
{
    return $this->instance($abstract, Mockery::mock(...array_filter(func_get_args())));
}

protected function instance($abstract, $instance)
{
    $this->app->instance($abstract, $instance);

    return $instance;
}
```

### Unit testing vs integration testing

Btw this test is not a unit test, but an integration test. If you include  a framework dependency (like in this case the Command), it is an integration test (the integration between your business logic and the framework). So my advice is to write your business logic in a separate service and then inject this service into the command. Then you you can unit test the service separately.